# Xlib. How to ignore all but one modifiers with XGrabKey?

Tags: x11

I have the following:

```
XGrabButton(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_C), Mod1Mask | KeyPressMask, window, false, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
```

The goal is to capture Alt+Shift+C so I can use the combination to close windows. This works unless I have another modifier active. For example, CapsLock, NumLock, ctrl, ect.

How can I tell it to ignore all the other modifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the best way to do this is to avoid specifying a modifier at all. Instead I use `AnyModifier` and check if the modifier I require is active using `event.state` in XButtonEvent:

```
XGrabKey(DISPLAY, XKeysymToKeycode(DISPLAY, XK_C), AnyModifier, frame, false, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeSync);
```

```
void WindowManager::OnKeyPress(const XKeyEvent& event)
{
    if(!(event.state & Mod1Mask))
    {
        return;
    }

    //Handle buttons...
}
```